# What does the "Data Panel" licence do in Business Auther?

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-webplayer

I am trying to figure out what should the "Data Panel" option (see image below) enable/disable when I am accessing the Web Player (in Edit mode). I've tried enabling/disabling it but nothing seems to change (or at least, I am not seeing it).

[image]

This is my Web Player node in Edit Mode:

[image]

### Edit

Enabling/Disabling the "Data Panel" option, does show an additional icon on the left-hand side of the Web Player. (Thanks to Mark P.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in the web player, you can click the circled "Data" button and the Data Panel will open as shown. Does that feature go away without the license?

[image]

This panel allows you to see sources, change them out, modify joins, transformations, etc., as well as see other data quality attributes (distinct values, nulls, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mark. However, I am afraid I don't have this button in my web player (I've updated my question to include a screenshot of my web player)

Comment: You should have one more icon on that left panel that is equivalent to the Data Panel that I have in my version of spotfire (as seen here in the global overview section: https://www.syntelli.com/the-new-and-improved-tibco-spotfire-x-interface). Does that button change depending on the license selected? Make sure you are testing properly as modifying Business Author may not change what you see, but may change what others see.

Comment: I see now. Enabling "Data Panel" did show an additional icon as you suggested on the left-hand side: https://ibb.co/BNxfDrj Thank you very much! :)